# Question about the war strategy in the 4th great ninja war

Tags: naruto

So when Shikaku was explaining the war strategy, he said Mifune's company will go to assist Darui's company.

But then Mifune went to fight Hanzo and help the commando unit..how did that happen? I thought Mifune was supposed to help Darui...

Comment: What's confusing about it? I mean, during war you can still assist another division if needed.

Answer (score 2):

In the 4th Great Ninja War, [Mifune](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mifune) was apart of the 5th Division. This division was designed to support any other company that was in need of assistance. So he sent units to both Darui's and Kitsuchi's divisions.

> Mifune is placed in charge of the [Fifth Division](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Fifth_Division). Because the Fifth Division is intended to reinforce the other divisions as the need arises, Mifune sends portions of his division to support the [Second Division](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Second_Division) and [First Division](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/First_Division)

However, Mifune fought Hanzo in the past and lost the battle

> During their battle Hanzō's kusarigama broke through Mifune's sword and struck his head, poisoning him. With the battle finished, Hanzō expressed his beliefs to him, and, acknowledging his faith and strength, gave Mifune the antidote for the poison and left

Mifune wanted to battle Hanzō in the efforts to bring down the enemy that originally defeated him

> Wishing to fight Hanzō by himself, Mifune instructs his samurai not to interfere.